# How to get total yes value from a set of survey question

Tags: javascript, html

I have a short survey questions with answer YES/ NO
How can I get the total number of YES when submit button is clicked?
I will need to display certain images later according to the number of YES

```
    <form>
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">This is question number 1</label>
        <div class="control">
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="1">
            Yes
          </label>
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question1" value="0">
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">This is question number 2</label>
        <div class="control">
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="1">
            Yes
          </label>
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question2" value="0">
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">This is question number 3</label>
        <div class="control">
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="1">
            Yes
          </label>
          <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question3" value="0">
            No
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field is-grouped">
        <div class="control">
          <div class="button is-link" onclick="countYes()">Submit</div>
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <button class="button is-link is-light">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    
   <script>
   function countYes() {
    totalVal = 0;

    for(var y=0; y<3; y++)
    {
      var questionNo = document.getElementsByName("question" + y);
      for (i=0; i<questionNo.length; i++)
      {
        if (document.forms.question[i].checked==true)
        {
          totalVal = totalVal + parseInt(document.forms.question[i].value);
          console.log(totalVal);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
```

I have a short survey questions with answer YES/ NO
How can I get the total number of YES when submit button is clicked?
I will need to display certain images later according to the number of YES

Comment: There is an easier approach to this. Consider using `document.querySelectorAll()` passing it this CSS selector: `form input[type="radio"][value="1"]:checked` https://jsfiddle.net/4mdjabg1/1/

Comment: Hi @GrafiCode , you have saved my day. This is exactly what I am hoping to achieve, many many thanks for sharing this so much easier solution, I have learnt a lot., thank you so much.